# Why won't my tweet button appear on my page?

Tags: html, css, twitter

My tweet button suddenly stopped appearing on my page. I am using one inside of the bootstrap grid system. There are no CSS styles attached to the tweet button apart from the default styles set by twitter.

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="padding-top: 5px;">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/intent?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&url=a" class="twitter-share-button"  data-text="#CM0677 Top Bait " data-size="large" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
            <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

            <ul class="list-unstyled" id="tweet-list">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

tweet-list is populated with tweets from the Standard Search API programatically through JS and does not affect the tweet button.

Any help is much appreciated :)

[Image of Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4dzD.png)

```
<div id="widget">
  <div class="btn-o" data-scribe="component:button" style="width: 0px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Ftopbait.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com%2F&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&amp;text=%23CM0677%20Top%20Bait%20&amp;tw_p=tweetbutton&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Ftopbait.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com%2F" class="btn" id="b"><i></i><span class="label" id="l">Tweet</span></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. can you send the screenshot of your button?.. 2. please check the "styles" tab on google chrome console. it may have other styles applied to the button..

Comment: @Fadhil I added a link to a screenshot. I also added the HTML of an element i just found that has a width of 0. When i increase this width the button shows but only partly. the issue is that this element is added by the Twitter widgets script (i think), so there is little i can do apart from edit the HTML and script tags that i initially put into the document.

Comment: @Fadhil it appears that if i remove the twitter widgets script tag from the document then the tweet button shows but only as a regular HTML <a> tag. So surely the issue is with the twitter widgets script?

Comment: can you update the pic of the css code on the console? i want to know what is the css `display` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Tweet button doesn't work in Opera. I'm not sure why, but the tweet button appears in other popular browsers.